# in Shell Scirpt I want to use ::ssu <USERNAME>

Tags: shell

I want to `ssu` or alternate command in shell script. However it's asking for password in middle of shell script. I don't want to do that.

Any alternate command or suggestion?

E.g.

```
ssu <username>
cp -r /path/
ksh wrapper.ksh
```

after finish `wrapper.ksh`, exit from `ssu` mode.

Comment: What Linux are you running, the last inclusion of `ssu` in Ubuntu  was in 8.10

Comment: which version

/opt/SUNWspro/bin/version

Comment: Do a `uname -a`, and edit your question with what you get.

Comment: uname -a

AIX an05101 1 6 00F61FD24C00

Answer (score 0):

If your shell script doesn't run for such a long time that `ssu` prompts you again, you can put

```
ssu -c echo 'initiating ssu'
```

at the top of your shell script, so it will immediately prompt and won't (unless running too slow) when the other `ssu` is executed.

Comment: i tried but getting below msg.

$ ssu -c echo 'initiating ssu'
You are not allowed to su to initiating ssu

Comment: I cannot run ssu on any of my machines, so I cannot really try things. Maybe you have to put the argument to `-c` in quotes: `ssu -c "echo initiating"`

Comment: uname -a
AIX an05101 1 6 00F61FD24C00